# »Wir würden es dir gesagt haben« vs. »Wir hätten es dir gesagt«

Tags: translation, english-to-german, subjunctive

Ich versuchte, folgenden Satz ins Deutsche zu übersetzen:

> We would have told you.

Ich dachte, dass Folgendes richtig wäre:

> Wir würden es dir gesagt haben.

Aber mir wurde gesagt, dass die richtige Übersetzung sei:

> Wir hätten es dir gesagt.

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen diesen zwei Übersetzungen? Sind beide richtig? Ist es generell richtig, eine Konstruktion mit *würde ... haben* zu benutzen, anstatt dem einfacheren *hätte?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Hätte* ist definitiv besser als *würde haben*.

Im Kontext wurde dein Satz vermutlich benutzt, um zu sagen: "Warum hast du nicht gefragt? Wir hätten es dir auf jeden Fall gesagt!"

Meine Vermutung, dass deine Übersetzung trozdem korrekt ist (wenn auch sehr unüblich) wurde von EM1 bestätigt, da dieser herausgefunden hat, dass der Konjunktiv II Plusquamperfekt durch würde + Infinitiv Perfekt (Konjunktiv II Futur II) ersetzt werden kann.

Da diese Form äußerst unbekannt ist, rate ich von der Benutzung ab.

Für mich persönlich sorgt der ungewöhnliche Gebrauch des Wortes *würde* für eine Verunsicherung des Satzes. Dies ist nicht korrekt und ich weiß nicht, warum dies so ist. Solange man nicht genau über diese Ausnahme informiert ist und diese gerne anderen Menschen erklärt, sollte man also von dem Gebrauch absehen.

Comment: Mit der Moeglichkeitsform hast du Recht. Danke!

Comment: Ich würde das "möglicherweise" weglassen, da diese "Möglichkeit" ist Original nicht erkennbar. In deinem Beispiel schreibst du ja selbst auch "auf jeden Fall".

Answer (score 6):

Im Englischen wird Conditional Type 3 durch "would + have + past-participle" gebildet.

Im Deutschen hingegen wird der entsprechende Konditionalsatz mit dem Konjunktiv II Plusquamperfekt gebildet (in deinem Fall "hätte" plus Partizip II).

Beispiele:

> Wenn ich Zeit gehabt hätte, wäre ich zur Party gekommen.
>
> Wenn du uns gefragt hättest, **hätten wir es dir gesagt.**

In deinem Satz ist der Bedingungssatz ausgelassen und im Deutschen werden dann natürlich die Wörter in eine andere Reihenfolge gebracht.

Eine *würde*-Form kommt hier nur äußerst selten zum Einsatz. [Canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Verb/Modi/Bedingungssatz.html):

> Zum Ausdruck der Vergangenheit verwendet man den Konjunktiv II Plusquamperfekt oder selten die Form würde + Infinitiv Perfekt (Konjunktiv II Futur II)

Durchaus häufig wird aber der Konjunktiv II Präteritum mit *würde* gebildet.

> Wenn ich Zeit hätte, käme ich zur Party.
> Wenn ich Zeit hätte, *würde* ich zur Party kommen.

---

Ich hatte die Frage versehentlich erst in Englisch beantwortet. Hier die englische Fassung:

In English the conditional type 3 is built up with "would + have + past participle".

In German, however, that conditional type is built up with Konjunktiv II Plusquamperfekt (in your case "hätte" plus past-participle).

Examples:

> If I had had the time, I would have came to the party. -> Wenn ich Zeit gehabt hätte, wäre ich zur Party gekommen.
>
> If you had asked us, **we would have told you**. -> Wenn du uns gefragt hättest, **hätten wir es dir gesagt.**

In your sentence the if-clause is omitted and that naturally requires in German that you reorder the words.

It's a very rare occasion that you apply a form with *würde*. [Canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Verb/Modi/Bedingungssatz.html):

> Zum Ausdruck der Vergangenheit verwendet man den Konjunktiv II Plusquamperfekt oder selten die Form würde + Infinitiv Perfekt (Konjunktiv II Futur II)

We often substitute Konjunktiv II Präteritum (conditional type 2) with *würde* though.

> Wenn ich Zeit hätte, käme ich zur Party.
> Wenn ich Zeit hätte, *würde* ich zur Party kommen.

Answer (score 2):

Erstmal ist der Satz, den Du übersetzen möchtest, vermutlich der zweite Teil eines irrealen Bedingungsgefüges, z. B.:

> Why didn’t you ask? We would have told you?
>   Warum hast du nicht gefragt? Wir hätten es dir gesagt.

Oder, um den Lehrbuch-Satzbau zu nehmen:

> If you had asked us, we would have told you.
>   Wenn du gefragt hättest, hätten wir es dir gesagt.

In jedem Fall hat der Angesprochene (»du«) eben nicht gefragt, womit die Situation irreal und also im Deutschen in den Irrealis zu setzen ist. Im Gegensatz zum Englischen werden dabei im Deutschen beide Hälften grammatikalisch gleich behandelt.

Nun wird der Irrealis im Deutschen bevorzugt durch den Konjunktiv II ausgedrückt, also in Deinem Beispiel mit *hätten gesagt* (Konjunktiv II der Vergangenheit). Als Alternative hierzu existiert die »*würde*-Form«, in Deinem Beispiel *würde gesagt haben.* Diese Form ist identisch mit dem Konjunktiv II des Futurs bzw. des Futurs II *(werde gesagt haben → würde gesagt haben).* Die Ersetzung des Konjunktivs II durch die *würde*-Form unterliegt aber gewissen Einschränkungen:

- Falls der Konjunktiv II identisch mit der entsprechenden Präteritumsform ist, ist die Ersetzung der Regelfall. Zum Beispiel:

  > Wenn sie arbeiteten, … → Wenn sie arbeiten würden, …
  >   Wenn sie gingen, … → Wenn sie gehen würden, …
- Falls dies nicht zutrifft und das Verb nicht als Hilfsverb verwendet werden kann, ist die Ersetzung zumindest in der Umgangssprache sehr üblich:

  > Wenn sie sähen, … (→) Wenn sie sehen würden, …
  >   Wenn er ginge, … (→) Wenn er gehen würde, …
- Bei Verben, die als Hilfsverben verwendet werden können (z. B. *sein, haben, können)* und insbesondere zur Bildung des Konjunktivs II der Vergangenheit ist die Ersetzung gänzlich unüblich:

  > Wenn sie wären, … ↛ Wenn sie sein würden, …
  >   Wenn sie gefragt hätten, …  ↛ Wenn sie gefragt haben würden, …

Deswegen würde ich »wir würden es dir gesagt haben« als falsch ansehen – außer Du möchtest hier wirklich das Futur II in den Konjunktiv setzen, wofür mir noch nicht einmal ein sinnvoller Beispielkontext zu Deinem Satz einfällt.

Comment: Der englische Lehrbuch-Satz würde korrekterweise "If you **had** asked us, we would have told you" lauten. Oder "If you asked us, we would **tell** you". In deinem Fall hast du Cond. Type 2 und 3 vermischt. Des Weiteren handelt es sich hier konkret um ein Beispiel im Type 3, wo es sich um den K2 der **Vorvergangenheit** handelt. Und beim Type 3 (Irreale Bedingung in der Vergangenheit) wird imho die würde-Form *nie* angewendet. Deine Beispiele beziehen sich auch alle auf Type 2 (Irreale Bedingung in der Gegenwart).

Comment: Was den englischen Satz betrifft, hast Du recht. Was den Rest betrifft, so sehe ich keinen Konflikt mit meiner Antwort, ich behandle die Vergangenheitsformen halt nur als Spezialfälle. Und da der Konjunktiv II der Vergangenheit immer mit einem Hilfsverb daherkommt, fällt er halt automatisch unter den letzten Punkt. (Nebenbei gibt es keinen *Konjunktiv II der Vorvergangenheit,* sondern nur den *Konjunktiv II der Vergangenheit* oder den *Konjunktiv der Vorvergangenheit* – je nachdem, welche Terminologie man verwendet.)

Comment: Mein Punkt war, dass "wir hätten gesagt" Plusquamperfekt ist.

Comment: Das hängt von Deiner Definition von *Plusquamperfekt* ab. Es ist entweder der Konjunktiv II von *wir haben gesagt* (und damit von einer Perfekt-Form) oder es ist der Konjunktiv von *wir hatten gesagt* (einer Plusquamperfekt-Form). Inhaltlich ist es auf jeden Fall etwas Irreales, das in der Vergangenheit liegt. Das Deutsche hat keine Möglichkeit, etwas Irreales in der Vorvergangenheit auszudrücken.

Comment: [canoo.net](http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Verb/Modi/Bedingungssatz.html): "Zum Ausdruck der Vergangenheit verwendet man den Konjunktiv II Plusquamperfekt oder selten die Form würde + Infinitiv Perfekt (Konjunktiv II Futur II)"

Comment: Das ist aber extrem inkonsequent, wenn die würde-Form als *Konjunktiv II Futur II* bezeichnet wird, müsste der Konjunktiv II der Vergangenheit (hätte gefragt) analog als *Konjunktiv II Perfekt* bezeichnet werden. Ich gestehe aber ein, dass diese Beizeichnung tatsächlich verwendet wird.

Comment: Ok, an der Stelle steige ich aus, weil ich dir nicht mehr folgen kann. Ich kann nicht sagen, ob es inkonsequent ist oder doch logisch. Ich finde es zumindest durchaus nachvollziehbar und schlüssig.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20629/discussion-between-wrzlprmft-and-em1).