# irreale Bedingungssätze in der Vergangenheit – »hätte« vs. »würde«

Tags: verb, subjunctive, tense

I am doing some exercises about “irreale Bedingungssätze in der Vergangenheit”. 
I am struggling with the way I should build the verb, which I find really quiet complicated. Especially, I am never sure whether I should use *hätten* or *würden* as auxiliary verb.

#### Example

Original meaning of the sentence and basically what I am trying to say is:

> Franz hat nicht fleißig genug gelernt. Deshalb musste er die Prüfung wiederholen.

Sentence:

> Wenn er fleißig genug gelernt hätte, **hätte / würde** er die Prüfung nicht wiederholen müssen.

Should I use *hätte* or *würde* here or would they both be okay?

Comment: Related: http://german.stackexchange.com/q/23346/2594

Comment: Related: [»Wir würden es dir gesagt haben« vs. »Wir hätten es dir gesagt«](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/20411/9551)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent (*würde-Umschreibung*) to

> - Wenn er fleißig genug gelernt hätte, ***hätte*** er die Prüfung nicht wiederholen müssen.

wäre

> - Wenn er fleißig genug gelernt hätte, ***würde*** er die Prüfung nicht wiederholt ***haben*** müssen.

---

And *'that's'* why we rather use the first one ;-)  Especially when it comes to constructions with modal verbs! In simpler sentences you might hear both, depending on where you are.

> - Wenn er fleißig genug gelernt hätte, ***hätte*** er auch die Prüfung nicht vermasselt.
> - Wenn er fleißig genug gelernt hätte, ***würde*** er auch die Prüfung nicht vermasselt ***haben***.

This is more or less like the regional differences between using *'Imperfekt'* or *'Perfekt'*!

---

> - Wenn er fleißig genug gelernt hätte, ***würde*** er die Prüfung nicht wiederholen müssen.

This means that either *now* or in the *future* he *'wouldn't have to repeat the exam'*!

---

In the very first example you can clearly sense how the future-conjunctive II is loosing its flavor of expressing something that is likely yet to happen in the future in favor of the intrinsic meaning of the *'würde-Umschreibung'*, which clearly refers to the past! e.g.

> - Wenn er noch fleißig genug lernen würde, ***würde*** er die Prüfung morgen Mittag schon hinter sich gebracht ***haben***.

So it is identically constructed like a future-indicative II

> - Wenn er noch fleißig genug lernt, ***wird*** er die Prüfung morgen Mittag schon hinter sich gebracht ***haben***.

---

So your question should actually better be something like

- Irreale Bedingungssätze in der Vergangenheit – »**hätte**« vs. »**würde haben**«

Comment: Konjunktiv II mit *würde* is not an *Umschreibung* (paraphrase), but an analytical form of Konjunktiv II. Many grammars use this and completely ignore analytical language morphology.

Answer (score 1):

No, only "hätte". is right in this context.
"würde" does imply that the test will take in the future.

Have a look here:
http://www.mein-deutschbuch.de/lernen.php?menu_id=37

Comment: *Würde* only has temporal meaning in a few contexts, and I don't see it here. It just is an analytical form of Konjunktiv II replacing *müsste*.